# Can I use two different versions of the Polymer in the same project?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

I have a problem when using `webcomponents` written using **Polymer 2.0** in the project which already has the components of **Polymer 1.5**.

> **There is an error:**
>
> ```
> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on
> 'Document': Registration failed for type 'dom-module'. A type with
> that name is already registered.
> ```

As I understand the error arises from the conflict between the two versions of the Polymer on the page. (both versions are attempting to create a global object Polymer)

Is there any way to allow use of two different versions of the Polymer on the same page? (something similar to `jQuery.noConflict()`)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure on having two separate versions at the same time, I do know that they are still working on the hybrid mode for 2.0 so you can run both 1.7 and 2.0 elements side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it works to have polymer 2.0 on the page as the only version, its compatibility support is well enough so that 1.x components do run after a few adaptations in templates and styles.